How to display axis tick labels with a detailed scientific notation offset?
I am trying to produce a figure with multiple subplots where the axis tick labels of each subplot should be formatting in the same way. As the numbers are large, displaying tick labels in a legible format is tricky. I like the matplotlib format of a detailed scientific offset b x 10^c (see plot below on right) where the displayed tick labels a can be then interpreted as (b+a) x 10^c.
However, I cannot find out how to control the use of this tick label formatter. It seems to me that matplotlib decides the use it very inconsistently.
This is my initial code which yields the subsequent plot:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

targets = [[-167297.54344731, -167301.10372634, -167308.44207031, -167312.11313287],[-145434.59446349, -145430.40561915, -145432.73985156, -145432.6785802]]
preds = [[-167298.46656051, -167300.59898357, -167308.72554459, -167311.71904965],[-145433.43693344, -145429.41508183, -145432.73929695, -145431.94648615]]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

# For each subplot
for i in range(2):

    # make subplot square    
    min_max = [min(targets[i]+preds[i]), max(targets[i]+preds[i])]
    offset = 2
    axs[i].set_ylim(min_max[0]-offset, min_max[1]+offset)
    axs[i].set_xlim(min_max[0]-offset, min_max[1]+offset)
    axs[i].set_aspect("equal")
    
    axs[i].scatter(targets[i], preds[i])


I want the format of the left plot to look like the one on the right:

I have tried using matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter which allows me to get the tick labels of the form 10^c instead of the desired b x 10^c. Setting axs[i].xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(4)) also seems to intermittently have an effect on whether or not the desired format is used.
So, my question is: how can I force the use of a tick label offset with a scientific notation format of b x 10^c?

Using matplotlib.ticker can provide a solution indeed.
formatter = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=True, useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(True)
formatter.set_powerlimits((-3, 4))  # define when to apply scientific notation

axs[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
axs[i].yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

powerlimits defines which numbers are shown in scientific and which in decimal notation, referring to the exponents of 10. Outside the interval it will be scientific, inside decimal.
Resulting in:


Thank you for your response but I am looking for how to set the y-axis ticks to be the same as the x-axis ticks as shown on the right plot. Instead of x10^5 as the offset, I want it to be -1.673x10^5.

Okay, I can see the problem now. Sorry, I didn't realize this goal first. I tried to look into this but could not find a solution using ScalarFormatter but it may be possible to find a hack

I have found such an alternative, please see my new answer.

You can normalize all your data without using ScalarFormatter and set the desired format for the plot independently.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

targets = [[-167297.54344731, -167301.10372634, -167308.44207031, -167312.11313287],
           [-145434.59446349, -145430.40561915, -145432.73985156, -145432.6785802]]

preds = [[-167298.46656051, -167300.59898357, -167308.72554459, -167311.71904965],
         [-145433.43693344, -145429.41508183, -145432.73929695, -145431.94648615]]


targets_array = np.array(targets)
preds_array = np.array(preds)

targets_array_a = targets_array[1, :] + 1.454e5
preds_array_a = preds_array[1, :] + 1.454e5
preds_array_b = preds_array[0, :] + 1.673e5
targets_array_b = targets_array[0, :] + 1.673e5


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize = (8, 4))

ax[0].scatter(targets_array_b, preds_array_b)
ax[1].scatter(targets_array_a, preds_array_a)


ax[0].annotate(r"-1.673×10$^{-5}$", xy=(0.7, -0.17), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(10, 0), 
                   textcoords='offset points', ha='left', va='bottom', fontsize=10)

ax[0].annotate(r"-1.673×10$^{-5}$", xy=(0, 1.0), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(0, 10), 
                   textcoords='offset points', ha='left', va='bottom', fontsize=10)


ax[1].annotate(r"-1.454×10$^{-5}$", xy=(0.7, -0.17), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(10, 0), 
                   textcoords='offset points', ha='left', va='bottom', fontsize=10)

ax[1].annotate(r"-1.454×10$^{-5}$", xy=(0, 1.0), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(0, 10), 
                   textcoords='offset points', ha='left', va='bottom', fontsize=10)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Resulting in:

In case, this answer provides a solution to your problem, you can accept it.
